# Laravel custom command argument with dash

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I got a custom command in Laravel 5, that gets username and password.

One user got his password starting with a dash, something like -819830219', making laravel return a error saying "The -8 option does not exist.

I tried setting the password between quotation marks and still got the same error.

Is there a way to pass a parameter that starts with a dash that laravel will not understand as a option?

```
protected function getArguments()
{
    return [
        ['username', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Partner\'s username.'],
        ['password', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Partner\'s password.'],
        ['origin', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Partner\'s origin code.'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: what exact code are you processing the password with? this seems odd

Comment: I've add on the main question.

Comment: escape dash? http://superuser.com/questions/163515/bash-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-containing-special-characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape the `-` character by prepending it with `--` like:

```
php artisan command -- -819830219
```

Or you can use an interactive command like this:

```
public function handle()
{
    $username = $this->ask('Enter username');
    $password = $this->secret('Enter password');
    $origin = $this->ask('Enter origin');
    $this->doSomething($username, $password, $origin);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I been in the same situation, it seems to be an issue with arguments.

Another option beside to ask interactive is to use options, with with option this problem does not happen.

For example

`protected $signature = 'project:command {--profile=} {--tz=}';`

then

`$profile_id = $this->option('profile', '');
 $timezone = $this->option('tz', '+00:00');`

The call to the command will look like this

`artisan project:command --profile=1609 --tz=-04:00`

Regards